# How to update PostgreSQL DB in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, database, postgresql, intellij-idea, datagrip

I am new to Databases.
I have create a new DB using pgAdmin (through browser). But as I connect to it through Intellij Idea - my new DB ( that is called "my_DB" ) is not being shown.

I would appreciate a lot if you could tell me, why is it so.
[image: Creating new DB]
[image: Having no DB in Intellij Idea]

Upd:I can do stuff with tables in my DB, but it is still underlined red and not being shown.
[image: Upd]

Comment: You need to select schemas. Just click `0 of 3` right next to the folder `postgres`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select ( 1 of 2 ) on the right side of DB entry in IntelliJ and select your Database to show